# Incorrect Survival Rate Percentage Calculation for Gender-Based Analysis in Titanic Dataset

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a data analysis project using R, where I'm trying to analyze the survival rate of passengers by gender using the Titanic dataset.The problem is that the calculated percentage in titanic_table is not showing the correct survival rate for male and female passengers. I've double-checked the data and the code logic, but I'm unable to figure out what's causing the issue.

This is the code

```
titanic_table <- train_data %>% group_by(Survived, Sex) %>% summarize(number = n()) %>% mutate(Survived = factor(Survived, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),total_number = sum(number), percentage = (number/total_number)*100)

plot_data <- data.frame(Sex = train_data$Sex, Age = train_data$Age, Survived = train_data$Survived, Predication = prediction)
ggplot(titanic_table , aes(x = Sex, fill = Survived)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar() + labs(y = "Passenger Count", title = "Titanic Survival")
```

I expected the calculated titanic_table to display the accurate survival rate percentages for both male and female passengers based on the Survived and Sex columns. These percentages should reflect the proportion of passengers who survived within each gender category.

Comment: I think you need to swap your group_by order. You are currently calculating what share of survived were men or women and what share of not survived were men or women, not what share of men or women survived. That’s because summarize collapses the last-invoked group_by, so your summary will be finding rates within each category of Survived, not each category of Sex.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help others help you, please make examples in your question reproducible: include used libraries, include enough data to demonstrate the issue, preferably as `dput()` output (in this case it would be ideal if you'd sample ~10 rows from the dataset, only including relevant columns),  include or describe desired result (with just ~10 rows it's not that difficult). You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  for more details.

Comment: Looks like you're using a training subset, so statistics will differ somewhat from those calculated for the whole dataset (other issues notwithstanding).

Comment: Learn to appreciate the effects of sampling.